# Marshaling two-dimensional array

Tags: c#, c++, .net, marshalling

I want to marshal two-dimensional array

```
int [10][20] //const dimensions size
```

from C++ dll to C# code. Is there automatic marshaler for that? Can't find good solution for such easy task.

```
    public int[,] _operators;
```

Gives undefined values.
Yes, i can make it one dimensional only for marshaling and then read it again to 2 dimsions in C#, but is there automatic easy way?

=================

The best way i think is using of pointer like this:

```
            const int 1dSize = 10;
            const int 2dSize = 10;
            var ret = new int[1dSize, 2dSize];

        unsafe
        {
            int* ptrOnArray = NativeLibPrototypes.Get2DArrayPtr();
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 1dSize; i1++)
            {
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 2dSize; i2++)
                {
                    ret[i1, i2] = *ptrOnArray;
                    ptrOnArray++;
                }
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 200)]
int[] _operators;
```

The size should be the number of elements in your array.

Check this [Default Marshaling for Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: where you get undefined ??

Comment: When i look in debugger _operators i see "?" at each element, _operators[0, 0] gives me index out of range...(_operators is the field of C++ class, now i comment everything except of _operators)

Comment: Tested one more time with empty project - [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 200)] works good only to 1d arrays, to 2d -the same, don't works